# javascript in partial view mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have partial view named MyPView contains a javascript

```
function loadMe(){
alert('Done');
}
```

and a _layout with a

```
ajax.ActionLink("MyTrouble","Controller","MyPView",
                 new ajaxOption{ OnSuccess="loadMe"})
```

. I want to run loadMe function when the partial loads but, it doesn't.

I know that I can put loadMe function in _layout but I dont want to do that, is there any other way to run that function?

Thank you all, and specially Youm who answer this. ;)

Comment: Why you want to put loadMe() on the partial? Is it bcos of different alert values?

Comment: don't know if relevant to your solution, but you should also add `{ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "yourdiv"}` to your AjaxOptions

Comment: Maybe 'OnSuccess' is not even called. If you have any error in action, then 'OnFailure' will be called

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery**, place the below JavaScript code inside your partial view:

```
$(function(){
  alert('Done');
});
```

OR

```
$(function(){
  loadMe();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(document).ready(loadMe)` on your partial view to achieve your goal. It will execute your loadMe function after full document will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```